# Refreshing Semantic UI sticky with Ember does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, ember.js, semantic-ui

I have this Semantic UI sticky rails menu in an Ember application that I need to refresh after the page is rendered completely, because currently it jumps or scrolls out of bound when the document height is changed.

```
setTimeout(function(){
 $('.ui.sticky').sticky({
  offset: 60,
  observeChanges: true,
  silent: true
 });
},2000);
```

It is wrapped into a setTimeout() to wait for the document content to load, which seemed to be the only workaround at that time. Also it is supposed to refresh every time content is added to or removed from the column, for example when the document image loads after the timeout or one of the accordions is opened/closed by the user. To achieve this I tried

```
$('.document-content.column').attr('onresize', "$('.ui.sticky').sticky('refresh')");
```

to catch changes in the element size. Unfortunately this only works when the window is resized. As I already found out, there is no event that triggers after images load, so I tried listening to DOM element changes with DOMSubtreeModified.

```
$('.document-content.column').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
 $('.ui.sticky').sticky('refresh');
});
```

This works fine and also substitutes the dirty timeout solution, but it's very slow on the initial page load, as it is triggered a bunch of times. Also DOMSubtreeModified is said to be deprecated, which is why I tried MutationObservers like this:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
  $('.ui.sticky').sticky('refresh');
});

var observerTarget = document.querySelector('.document-content.column');

var observerOptions = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
};

observer.observe(observerTarget, observerOptions);
```

But it seems that every refresh of the sticky just triggers the observer again, causing an endless loop. And now I don't know what else to do.

Short version of the hbs template:

```
<div class="ui stackable three column container relaxed grid">
 <div class="twothird wide document-content column">
  {{image-loader}}
  <div class="ui divider"></div>
  <h2 class="cap text">{{text}}</h2>
  <div class="ui relaxed divided accordion">
   <div class="title"></div>
   <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="widescreen large screen computer only column">
  <div class="ui sticky rail-menu">
   {{document-sidebar}}
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

If there is anything else I should provide, please tell me. I am thankful for any help that I can get.

Comment: Have you considered to use a positioning library with an ember addon instead? Like `ember-popper` or `ember-tether`? The other thing you could do is a requestAnimationFrame loop. But use an add-on if you can.

Comment: Do you have a sense of how this is done in non-Ember? Do you know about component lifecycle hooks? I think you could use didRender and didUpdateAttributes for a cleaner solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Okay, so I tried `ember-tether` and it didn't work. It rather broke our entire template without even giving an error message, although I like the idea of [tether.io](http://tether.io/), which it seemingly is based on. Ember-popper is allegedly still in alpha, so it was no option at all. I also tried `didRender()` in one of the first attempts but the hook fired too early. Also, `didUpdateAttrs()` fires before `didRender()`, so it didn't help either.*

### **What really did the trick was this library:**

http://marcj.github.io/css-element-queries/

I installed the NPM module and ran the constructor for the `ResizeSensor` in the `didInsertElement()` hook which fires the refresh function on every resize of the element and the sticky finally doesn't jump anymore or scrolls out of bound.

```
import ResizeSensor from 'npm:css-element-queries/src/ResizeSensor';

...

new ResizeSensor($('.document-content.column'), function(){
  $('.ui.sticky').sticky('refresh');
});
```